# how many android devices could be plugged into ubuntu server？

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

I plugged 7 android devices to my ubuntu server with usb cables, but adb devices command only shows six devices. Is there any limitation of the account of android devices？ Thanks.

Comment: Does the device not being listed show up if you remove one cable, so that you have only 6 devices connected? And: if you connect only 6 devices, does the port that had a connected device not show up work then?

Comment: If I remove one connected device , the 7th device will show up.

Comment: OK, and 6 devices work, regardless which of your 7 USB ports you choose?

Comment: Yeah. I am using a usb hub which owns 19 ports and 3 pc usb ports, but only 6 devices could be shown up. It might be the hub causing the issue too. I will try another usb hub. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#notlisted):

> The **adb devices** command has a corner-case command sequence that causes running emulator(s) to not show up in the **adb devices** output even though the emulator(s) are visible on your desktop. This happens when all of the following conditions are true:
>
> 1. The adb server is not running, and
> 2. You use the **emulator** command with the **-port** or **-ports** option with an odd-numbered port value between 5554 and 5584, and
> 3. The odd-numbered port you chose is not busy so the port connection can be made at the specified port number, or if it is busy, the emulator switches to another port that meets the requirements in 2, and
> 4. You start the adb server after you start the emulator.
>
> One way to avoid this situation is let the emulator choose its own ports, and don't run more than 16 emulators at once. Another way is to always start the adb server before you use the **emulator** command, as explained in the [following examples](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#notlisted).

I guess it should be pretty much the same concerning real devices too.